# android studio gives incompatible types when adding string to textview

Tags: java, android, textview, android-studio

so this is my first android app im writing

I could get solutions to other little issues i have had but this i'm not sure how to solve

```
package com.example.helloandroidstudio;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btnClick;
    private EditText Name, Date;
    private TextView msg, NameOut, DateOut;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button) ;
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textenter) ;
        Date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewOut) ;
        NameOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtoutName) ;
        DateOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutDate) ;

        msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//set visibility to false on create
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == btnClick)
        {
            if (Name.equals("") == false && Date.equals("") == false)
            {
                NameOut = Name;
                DateOut = Date;
                msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Please complete both fields"            <<<---PROBLEM-----
                msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }
```

the problem is, by the arrow, it gives an error:

Incompatible types,  required android.widget.textview    found Java.lang.string

Did I miss something, why is it giving me this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to assign `String` to the variable `msg` of type `TextView`

It should be

```
msg.setText("Please complete both fields")
```

Answer (score 0):

msg.setText("Please complete both fields");

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
msg.setText("Please complete both fields");
```